# CSS blur whole section, without blurring div inside

Tags: javascript, html

quick question.
I'm trying to blur a whole section on click, but I want a div inside that section to not be blurred with it.

I tried to change the properties of the div with, `important` and `.setProperty` with JS, but no luck.

```js
const handleClickCard = e => {
    const $currentCard = e.currentTarget;
    const $cardDiv = document.querySelector('.card1');
    const $bg = document.querySelector('.overleven');

    if ($currentCard.dataset.id === '1') {
      $cardDiv.style.display = 'initial';
      $bg.style.filter = 'blur(10px)';
      $cardDiv.style.setProperty('filter', 'none', 'important');
    }
  };
```

```html
<section class="overleven">
    <div class="overleven--wrapper">
      <p class="overleven--info overleven--info--title">Er zijn veel potentiële dreigingen tijdens hun trektocht naar het zuiden, dus moeten ze altijd alert blijven.</p>
      <p class="overleven--info overleven--info--subtitle">Klik op een vuurkaart om een bedreiging te onthullen.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
      <img data-id="1" src="./assets/longread/card.png" alt="een dreigingskaart" class="card">
      <img data-id="2" src="./assets/longread/card.png" alt="een dreigingskaart" class="card">
      <img data-id="3" src="./assets/longread/card.png" alt="een dreigingskaart" class="card">
  </div>
  <div class="card1">
  </div>
  <div class="card2"></div>
  <div class="card3"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Where is `handleClickCard` called?

Comment: in an `init()` function that I call at the end of my JS. The function does work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way rendering works, you can't blur a parent without blurring a child.  Rendering is done as a tree, with caching the entire way.

What you can do is blur all children except one:

```css
#items:hover * {
  filter: blur(3px);
}

#items:hover *:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
  <div>Hey</div>
  <div>Hallo</div>
  <div>Gutentag</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you guide me on how to translate this to a javascript scenario? Can I select the same way in Javascript as you showed me?

Comment: You could do something like `Array.from(document.cssQuerySelectorAll(".card")).forEach((card) => ....code omitted)`.  I recommend seeing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in JavaScript that will blur everything except the image that was clicked on. If you click in the `<section>` on something other than the image, it will all come back into focus.

```js
const sectionClick = (e) => {
  const clickedOn = e.target;
  const textWrapper = document.querySelector('.textWrapper');
  const cardWrapper = document.querySelector('.cardWrapper');
  const allCards = cardWrapper.children;

  if (clickedOn.parentElement === cardWrapper) {
    textWrapper.style.filter = 'blur(10px)';
    for (const element of allCards) {
      clickedOn === element ? element.style.filter = 'none' : element.style.filter = 'blur(10px)'
    }
  } else {
    textWrapper.style.filter = 'none';
    for (const element of allCards) {
      element.style.filter = 'none';
    }
  }
};
```

```css
.section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section" onclick="sectionClick(event)">
  <div class="textWrapper">
    <p> Amet do nulla dolore sit mollit cillum officia eu officia est aliqua eu. Aliqua dolore laborum reprehenderit fugiat aute sunt pariatur cillum qui tempor quis proident elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cardWrapper">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100.png" alt="image placeholder" class="card">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100.png" alt="image placeholder" class="card">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100.png" alt="image placeholder" class="card">
  </div>
</section>
```